# What is difference between contentprovider and contentResolver in android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

What is the difference between **ContentProviders** and **ContentResolver**? I do not want for the `SQLite` database. I am developing an application for media.

Comment: the same as between "to provide" and "to resolve" ... short: ContentProvider implementation provides some data for some authority ... ContentResolver resolve which provider(based on authority) should be used and ask this provider for data ...

Comment: @Selvin F I want to make a program for playlist than I think I must have to create the content provider.Please tell me how to create our own ContentProviders

Comment: https://queception.com/question.php?question=107

Comment: In case any of you have some networking basics, ContentResolver is analogous to domain name resolution, i.e. mapping stackoverflow.com to 151.101.129.69.The role of ContentResolver pretty much ends there.
ContentProvider serves the contents for a specific request like providing the HTML for this question "stackoverflow.com/questions/18874801".
It is really just an abstraction layer for querying a database, ignoring the underlying implementation

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I found some explanation [here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/content-resolvers-and-content-providers.html).  In summary

*Content Resolver* resolves a URI to a specific *Content provider*.

*Content Provider* provides an interface to query content.

The way to query a content provider is `contentResolverInstance.query(URI,.....)`

Comment: > if i want to create my playlist than whether I have to use the Contentprovider??

Comment: Yes.  Content Provider exposes an application's content to other applications.  You can also use it to retrieve data from a web server.

Comment: It is good explanation! But if the writer had explained "ContentProvider" first then it would had given more sense and sequence + more understanding! Anyhow! It clears the idea for me :)

Comment: Just to add. ContentResolver particularly needed when you access "other's" content providers to have a secure access. If you have your own content provider you don't need to use it.

Answer (score 53):

`ContentProviders` are used **to abstract the database from other parts** and acts as an interface between your database and UI/other classes. You must create your own ContentProvider **to share your app data with other apps**.

`ContentResolver` is used to select the right ContentProvider based on the `ContentUris`. A ContentUri may look like

> content://com.android.contacts/contacts/3

- **content://**  is called *scheme* and indicates that it is a ContentUri.
- **com.android.contacts** is called *Content authority* and ContentResolver uses it to resolve to a unique provider (in this case, ContactProvider).
- **contacts** is the *path* that identify some subset of the provider's data (for example, Table name).
- **3** is the *id* used to uniquely identify a row within the subset of data.

[image]

> NOTE : Your own app can also use this route to handle its data.

See [Content Providers in Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) for more detail

Comment: The number of upvotes indicates this answer should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, this answer is more clear than the accepted answer

Answer (score 24):

## Two layered Abstraction :

**ContentResolver --> ContentProvider -->SQLiteDatabase**

> **The main difference is this as mentioned in other answers.**
>
> ContentProvider exposes private data of your application to external application
>   while
>   ContentResolver provides the right ContentProvider among all the ContentProviders  using a URI.

### Deeper Understanding (of two-layered abstraction)

Let's take a detour.
We all know that when we create an SQLite database then the database remains private to your application which means, you just can not share your app data with any other external application.

#### How data is shared then?

ContentProvider and ContentResolver are part of `android.content` package. These two classes work together to provide robust, secure data sharing model among applications.
**ContentProvider** exposes data stored in the SQLite database to other application without telling them the underlying implementation of your database.
So it abstracts the SQliteDatabase. **But wait there is a catch** !!!
The external application can not directly access ContentProvider. For that, you need to first interact with another class called ContentResolver 
Think ContentResolver as a ContentProvider finder. There is only one instance of it and all the ContentProviders of your Device are registered with a simple Namespace URI. If you want to reach a particular ContentProvider you just need to know its URI. Pass it to ContentResolver and it will find the Provider using the URI.
Now lets have a look at the **most important method** `getContentResolver().query(URI,String[] proj.....)`

> What happens when `getContentResolver().query(URI,String[] proj.....)` gets called

`query()` method belongs to ContentResolver class however it invokes the abstract query() method of resolved ContentProvider and returns Cursor object.
In this way, the External application gets exposed to the private database via two abstraction layers.

> **Just to add more points**
>              You cannot create your own ContentResolver class but you can always create your own
>   ContentProvider class

Hope you have a better understanding
You can also see some sample code [here](https://github.com/rohitksingh/My_Android_Garage/tree/master/SQLiteDatabaseDemo/app/src/main/java/rohksin/com/sqlitedatabasedemo) for creating SQLitedatabase, ContentProvider etc, But it's not well documented.

Answer (score 6):

**In 2021 :D**

**Content Resolver** :  For Data Request

**Content Provider** : For Data Response