# Is there a way for fetching data when app closed and store it in db?

Tags: android

I am working on news reader application and now i want to achieve this:
Once a day when there is Internet connection or at a specific time for example at 23.00 my app will fetch all new news and then store it in db. Inside application I am using retrofit to fetch and room to store using mvvm pattern. How can I do this? Any suggestiions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using flex period in [PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder).
As example, if you want run your Worker within 15 minutes at the end of repeat interval (let's say 8 hours), code will look like this:

```
val periodicRefreshRequest = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
            RefreshWorker::class.java, // Your worker class
            8, // repeating interval
            TimeUnit.HOURS,
            15, // flex interval - worker will run somewhen within this period of time, but at the end of repeating interval
            TimeUnit.MINUTES
    )
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do this via Service in android it has below features -

**Foreground**

A foreground service performs some operation that is noticeable to the user. For example, an audio app would use a foreground service to play an audio track. Foreground services must display a Notification. Foreground services continue running even when the user isn't interacting with the app.

**Background**

A background service performs an operation that isn't directly noticed by the user. For example, if an app used a service to compact its storage, that would usually be a background service.

You can read more about this in below link -

[Service in Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

Comment: Service is not a good approach because you have to run it all the time best solution is Content Provider /Content Resolver https://stackoverflow.com/a/40562442/2692102

Comment: Why we have to run all the time without need whenever you work is finished you can stop the service it's simple as that.

Comment: @Hanzala can I achieve everything what I want using content Provider ??

Comment: explain about **eveything**

Comment: @DipankarBaghel what if device is restarted and service is not started again and we are willing to do some thing with that? and how service will receive data from any other application?

Comment: @Hanzala If device restarted then there is is a provision is service to restart it again with redelivering the previous Intent. I think you need to read about START_REDELIVER_INTENT, START_NOT_STICKY and START_STICKY. Hope this will clear your doubt.

Comment: Use Work manager  or Job Scheduler for this task.Run a service every time in background is bad approach. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50357066/periodic-daily-work-requests-using-workmanager

Comment: @White check my Answer

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services check this.

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanButt will you please explain running a service in background is a bad approach. where is this written? this will be helpful for me.

Comment: @Hanzala I didn't find anywhere that state's that service is a bad approach for background task. It recommends only to use updated api's and migration of service only for better use experience that's it.

Comment: @DipankarBaghel Services running in the background can consume device resources, potentially resulting in a worse user experience. this is not my line l copy paste this line from  https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Comment: @Hanzala I will check it